# Resources reference for engineering mathematics.

Tags: education

I am aware that this can be very subjective question but I am desperately in need of answer,

I am undergoing maths heavy courses like mass transfer, heat transfer, fluid mechanics, momentum phenomenon, computational Techniques etc, but problem is my weak mathematics.

I had course where topics like Linear Algebra, calculus, differential equations, complex analysis and transforms were taught but the quality of course wasn't good at all. I can solve the elementary questions from these topics but don't have any intuition for their application - which is creating challenges in other courses I mentioned.

I want to **learn from sractch** the mentioned topics in detail--*Linear Algebra, calculus, differential equations, complex analysis and transforms*-- so that I can have **strong intuition as well as rigor**.

How can this be done considering the fact that **I have limited time,but am ready to work extra hard**. **My question is:** *what are suggestions regarding resources for engineering mathematics and what should be the strategy ?*.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is no simple answer here unfortunately.

Comment: @copper.hat but that also means there's an answer 

Comment: I suggest broaching this topic with professors, both in the Math department, and the Engineering department, at a university.